# oracle compression AVG_ROW_LEN

Tags: oracle, exadata

Im trying to calculate the size of the table(Exadata database table).

I used the AVG_ROW_LEN from ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS and took Actual row count from table then did AVG_ROW_LEN * count(*).

Our table is partitioned and sub-partitioned. (and Compressed, COMPRESS_FOR=QUERY HIGH)

just wanted to understand is AVG_ROW_LEN attribute value changes for compressed table vs non compressed table?

Answer (score 0):

According to this AskTom answer, this is the average length of the rows when they are not compressed: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:8806017524595

You might test this with a small sample of data to confirm it.

Comment: thanks for quick respond David, i did a quick test. found AVG_ROW_LEN remains same before and after compression. i tried with  "ALTER TABLE test1 MOVE COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH;"